# "mvn test" does not copy contents of src/test/resources to the output directory?

Tags: maven

A datafile was updated under `src/test/resources`.  I had anticipated that when running

```
mvn test
```

that the latest version of that datafile would be copied to the output directory - which is `${PROJECT_ROOT}/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/` . However that did not happen. Instead it was necessary to run

```
mvn package
```

for the datafile to be synced.  Is there any way - short of invoking `mvn package` (which does a lot more work than required since the source files did not change) - to sync the output directories with the current source resources?

The output directories from the `pom.xml` are:

```
<outputDirectory>target/scala-${scala.binary.version}/classes</outputDirectory>
 <testOutputDirectory>target/scala-${scala.binary.version}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
```

The `mvn test` is not copying artifacts to either place.

Here is the core testing and packaging related portions of the `pom.xml` .

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>target/scala-${scala.binary.version}/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/scala-${scala.binary.version}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <!--<resources>-->
      <!--<resource>-->
        <!--<directory>src/test/resources</directory>-->
        <!--<targetPath>.</targetPath>-->
        <!--<includes>-->
          <!--<include>**/*</include>-->
        <!--</includes>-->
      <!--</resource>-->
    <!--</resources>-->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <scalaCompatVersion>${scala.binary.version}</scalaCompatVersion>
                <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
                <args>
                    <arg>-unchecked</arg>
                    <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                    <arg>-feature</arg>
                    <arg>-Xmacro-settings:materialize-derivations</arg>
                </args>
                <jvmArgs>
                    <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
                    <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
                </jvmArgs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <minimizeJar>false</minimizeJar>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                <parallel>false</parallel>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <suffixes>(?&lt;!Integration)(Test|Spec)</suffixes>
                        <stdout>G</stdout>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-test</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <suffixes>(?&lt;=Integration)(Test|Spec)</suffixes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Perhaps the resources:testResources goal is bound to a phase other than the default process-test-resources?

Comment: Without the pom file and project it's hard to guess what's wrong...

Comment: Fair enough - let me see about putting together a condensed version of the `pom.xml`

Comment: @RCB and @khmarbaise  the `pom.xml` core pieces were added to the question.

Comment: @RCB The `resources` phase is not directly referenced in the `pom.xml`.  ooc is it possible to "add" the `resources:testResources` manually - to enable it to do run independently from the `mvn package` ?